# Pandas multilevel indexing for time series data with different reference and publish dates

Tags: python, date, pandas, time-series, multi-level

I have accounting data that has both reference dates (i.e. the fiscal quarter end dates) and publish dates (i.e. when the actual earning were released). Below is a sample:

```
              item  Reference    Value VALUED  FQTR  FYEARQ
Published                                                  
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1983-12-31   13.820      3     1    1984
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1984-03-31   20.895      3     2    1984
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1984-06-30   26.764      3     3    1984
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1984-09-30   39.614      3     4    1984
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1984-12-31   15.056      3     1    1985
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1985-03-31   33.604      3     2    1985
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1985-06-30   42.719      3     3    1985
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1985-09-30   54.064      3     4    1985
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1985-12-31    6.510      3     1    1986
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1986-03-31   18.503      3     2    1986
1986-12-14   CAPXY 1986-06-30   48.071      3     3    1986
1987-01-31   CAPXY 1986-09-30   66.629      2     4    1986
1987-01-31   CAPXY 1986-09-30   66.629      3     4    1986
1987-03-31   CAPXY 1986-12-31   15.740      2     1    1987
1987-03-31   CAPXY 1986-12-31   15.740      3     1    1987
1987-05-31   CAPXY 1987-03-31   38.699      2     2    1987
1987-05-31   CAPXY 1987-03-31   38.699      3     2    1987
1987-08-31   CAPXY 1987-06-30   61.006      2     3    1987
1987-08-31   CAPXY 1987-06-30   61.006      3     3    1987
1987-12-31   CAPXY 1987-09-30   86.127      2     4    1987
1987-12-31   CAPXY 1987-09-30   86.127      3     4    1987
1988-03-31   CAPXY 1987-12-31   34.140      2     1    1988
1988-03-31   CAPXY 1987-12-31   34.140      3     1    1988
1988-06-09   CAPXY 1988-03-31   68.059      2     2    1988
1988-06-09   CAPXY 1988-03-31   68.059      3     2    1988
1988-09-08   CAPXY 1988-06-30  101.198      2     3    1988
1988-09-08   CAPXY 1988-06-30  101.198      3     3    1988
1988-12-30   CAPXY 1988-09-30  144.001      2     4    1988
1988-12-30   CAPXY 1988-09-30  144.001      3     4    1988
1989-03-09   CAPXY 1988-12-31   73.967      2     1    1989
...            ...        ...      ...    ...   ...     ...
2001-08-16  OANCFY 2001-06-30  -90.000      2     3    2001
2001-08-16  OANCFY 2001-06-30  -90.000      3     3    2001
2002-01-10  OANCFY 2001-09-30  185.000      2     4    2001
2002-01-10  OANCFY 2001-09-30  185.000      3     4    2001
2002-02-14  OANCFY 2001-12-31   42.000      2     1    2002
2002-02-14  OANCFY 2001-12-31   42.000      3     1    2002
2002-05-23  OANCFY 2002-03-31   44.000      2     2    2002
2002-05-23  OANCFY 2002-03-31   44.000      3     2    2002
2002-08-15  OANCFY 2002-06-30    7.000      2     3    2002
2002-08-15  OANCFY 2002-06-30    7.000      3     3    2002
2002-12-31  OANCFY 2002-09-30   89.000      2     4    2002
2002-12-31  OANCFY 2002-09-30   89.000      3     4    2002
2003-02-13  OANCFY 2002-12-31  110.000      2     1    2003
2003-02-13  OANCFY 2002-12-31  110.000      3     1    2003
2003-05-22  OANCFY 2003-03-31  208.000      2     2    2003
2003-05-22  OANCFY 2003-03-31  208.000      3     2    2003
2003-08-21  OANCFY 2003-06-30  216.000      3     3    2003
2003-08-21  OANCFY 2003-06-30  216.000      2     3    2003
2003-12-31  OANCFY 2003-09-30  289.000      2     4    2003
2003-12-31  OANCFY 2003-09-30  289.000      3     4    2003
2004-02-19  OANCFY 2003-12-31  219.000      2     1    2004
2004-02-19  OANCFY 2003-12-31  219.000      3     1    2004
2004-05-20  OANCFY 2004-03-31  280.000      2     2    2004
2004-05-20  OANCFY 2004-03-31  280.000      3     2    2004
2004-08-19  OANCFY 2004-06-30  491.000      2     3    2004
2004-08-19  OANCFY 2004-06-30  491.000      3     3    2004
2004-12-16  OANCFY 2004-09-30  934.000      2     4    2004
2004-12-16  OANCFY 2004-09-30  934.000      3     4    2004
2005-02-10  OANCFY 2004-12-31  775.000      2     1    2005
2005-02-10  OANCFY 2004-12-31  775.000      3     1    2005

[396 rows x 6 columns]
```

The data is imported via pandas.io.sql.read_sql to a dataframe
The problem is with indexing depending on the specific case whether the user requests the data by the reference date or the publish date. I then need to pivot the data and show each item as a column with a multi-level index for reference / publish date.. there can be many duplicate reference dates for a single publish date.

I thought about something like:

```
index = accdata
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([index.columns])
df = pd.DataFrame(accdata, index=index)
df.stack()
```

but I get the following error on creating the multiindex dataframe:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I figure this would be a fairly common problem where the reference date and the publish date aren't aligned but I cant seem to find an elegant solution.

Any thoughts?

From Alexander's comment, with an slight index adaptation, I was looking for something like:

```
df.reset_index().set_index(['Reference','Published'])
```

then, maybe this (for illustrative purposes):

```
pd.concat(df[df['item'] == 'CAPXY']), df[df['item'] == 'OANCFY'])
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

which then would return:

```
                         item    Value VALUED  FQTR  FYEARQ
Reference  Published                                       
1983-12-31 1986-12-14   CAPXY   13.820      3     1    1984
1984-03-31 1986-12-14   CAPXY   20.895      3     2    1984
1984-06-30 1986-12-14   CAPXY   26.764      3     3    1984
1984-09-30 1986-12-14   CAPXY   39.614      3     4    1984
1984-12-31 1986-12-14   CAPXY   15.056      3     1    1985
```

But iI was hoping to acheive something like the following:

```
First:                  CAPXY                        OANCFY
Second:                 Value VALUED  FQTR  FYEARQ   Value   VALUED   FQTR  FYEARQ
Reference  Published                                       
1983-12-31 1986-12-14   13.820      3     1    1984
1984-03-31 1986-12-14   20.895      3     2    1984
1984-06-30 1986-12-14   26.764      3     3    1984
1984-09-30 1986-12-14   39.614      3     4    1984
1984-12-31 1986-12-14   15.056      3     1    1985
```

so that the items are represented int the columns and the are all aligned (left joined) based on the reference and publish date

Answer (score 1):

Based on how your DataFrame printed out, it looks like it is currently indexed on Published.  You need to reset your index, and then reindex your DataFrame to:
    a) `item`
    b) `Reference`
    c) `Published`

```
>>> df.reset_index().set_index(['item', 'Reference', 'Published'])
                       index    Value  VALUED  FQTR  FYEARQ
item  Reference Published                                      
CAPXY 12/31/83  12/14/86       0   13.820       3     1    1984
      3/31/84   12/14/86       1   20.895       3     2    1984
      6/30/84   12/14/86       2   26.764       3     3    1984
      9/30/84   12/14/86       3   39.614       3     4    1984
      12/31/84  12/14/86       4   15.056       3     1    1985
      3/31/85   12/14/86       5   33.604       3     2    1985
```

EDIT:

Based on the revised post, I believe a pivot table would do the trick.  I also swap the column levels to get your desired format.

Note that you need to convert your dates to datetime objects (or timestamps) if they are strings.

```
import datetime as dt

df['Reference'] = df.Reference.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date())    
df['Published'] = df.Published.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date())


pt = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['Reference', 'FYEARQ', 'FQTR', 'Published'], 
                                  columns=['item'], 
                                  values=['Value', 'VALUED'])

pt.columns = pt.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)

>>> pt
item                                 CAPXY       
                                     Value VALUED
Reference  FYEARQ FQTR Published                 
1983-12-31 1984   1    1986-12-14   13.820    3.0
1984-03-31 1984   2    1986-12-14   20.895    3.0
1984-06-30 1984   3    1986-12-14   26.764    3.0
1984-09-30 1984   4    1986-12-14   39.614    3.0
1984-12-31 1985   1    1986-12-14   15.056    3.0
1985-03-31 1985   2    1986-12-14   33.604    3.0
1985-06-30 1985   3    1986-12-14   42.719    3.0
1985-09-30 1985   4    1986-12-14   54.064    3.0
1985-12-31 1986   1    1986-12-14    6.510    3.0
1986-03-31 1986   2    1986-12-14   18.503    3.0
1986-06-30 1986   3    1986-12-14   48.071    3.0
1986-09-30 1986   4    1987-01-31   66.629    2.5
1986-12-31 1987   1    1987-03-31   15.740    2.5
1987-03-31 1987   2    1987-05-31   38.699    2.5
1987-06-30 1987   3    1987-08-31   61.006    2.5
1987-09-30 1987   4    1987-12-31   86.127    2.5
1987-12-31 1988   1    1988-03-31   34.140    2.5
1988-03-31 1988   2    1988-06-09   68.059    2.5
1988-06-30 1988   3    1988-09-08  101.198    2.5
1988-09-30 1988   4    1988-12-30  144.001    2.5
1988-12-31 1989   1    1989-03-09   73.967    2.0
```

As an alternative, you can try `groupby` since all of your data is unique per index.

```
pt = df.reset_index().groupby(['Reference', 'FYEARQ', 'FQTR', 'item'])\
         ['Published', 'Value', 'VALUED'].first().unstack('item')

>>> pt
                         Published                Value        VALUED       
item                         CAPXY      OANCFY    CAPXY OANCFY  CAPXY OANCFY
Reference  FYEARQ FQTR                                                      
1983-12-31 1984   1     1986-12-14         NaN   13.820    NaN      3    NaN
1984-03-31 1984   2     1986-12-14         NaN   20.895    NaN      3    NaN
1984-06-30 1984   3     1986-12-14         NaN   26.764    NaN      3    NaN
1984-09-30 1984   4     1986-12-14         NaN   39.614    NaN      3    NaN
1984-12-31 1985   1     1986-12-14         NaN   15.056    NaN      3    NaN
1985-03-31 1985   2     1986-12-14         NaN   33.604    NaN      3    NaN
1985-06-30 1985   3     1986-12-14         NaN   42.719    NaN      3    NaN
1985-09-30 1985   4     1986-12-14         NaN   54.064    NaN      3    NaN
1985-12-31 1986   1     1986-12-14         NaN    6.510    NaN      3    NaN
1986-03-31 1986   2     1986-12-14         NaN   18.503    NaN      3    NaN
1986-06-30 1986   3     1986-12-14         NaN   48.071    NaN      3    NaN
1986-09-30 1986   4     1987-01-31         NaN   66.629    NaN      2    NaN
1986-12-31 1987   1     1987-03-31         NaN   15.740    NaN      2    NaN
1987-03-31 1987   2     1987-05-31         NaN   38.699    NaN      2    NaN
1987-06-30 1987   3     1987-08-31         NaN   61.006    NaN      2    NaN
1987-09-30 1987   4     1987-12-31         NaN   86.127    NaN      2    NaN
1987-12-31 1988   1     1988-03-31         NaN   34.140    NaN      2    NaN
1988-03-31 1988   2     1988-06-09         NaN   68.059    NaN      2    NaN
1988-06-30 1988   3     1988-09-08         NaN  101.198    NaN      2    NaN
1988-09-30 1988   4     1988-12-30         NaN  144.001    NaN      2    NaN
1988-12-31 1989   1     1989-03-09         NaN   73.967    NaN      2    NaN
2001-06-30 2001   3            NaN  2001-08-16      NaN    -90    NaN      3
2001-09-30 2001   4            NaN  2002-01-10      NaN    185    NaN      2
2001-12-31 2002   1            NaN  2002-02-14      NaN     42    NaN      2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. That is really close to what I was trying to achieve.. but I wanted to have it so that the value/valued/fqtr/fyearq column is replaced under item name (i.e. in the above case 'CAPXY') so that the dataframe would represent each item as a different set of columns that are aligned (left joined?) on the reference and published dates.. any help is really appreciated..

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide an example of what you'd like the sample data to look like?

Comment: Do you just want a different ordering of the index (e.g. 'Published', 'item', 'Reference')? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: sorry if it was not so clear I made an edit to the original post, thanks